# A method calling other method in another class is not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

so i have two classes
It's supossed to be like a digital movie shop, so it should return the user names, the movie names and the rating of the movies
This is the interface one:

```
import modelo.Matriz;

public class MenuConsola {

private Matriz userItem;

public MenuConsola(){

    String[] peliculas =  { "Toy story2", "Jumanji", "Amelie", "Wolverine", "Spider Man", "Yes Men", "Sabrina",
            "Tom and Huck", "Sudden Death", "GoldenEye" };
    String[] usuarios = { "Jhon", "Michael", "Jimmy", "Janis", "Carla", "Angie" };
    userItem = new Matriz(peliculas, usuarios);
    cargarMatriz();
    mostrarBanner();

    mostrarUsuarios();
    System.out.println("\n");
    mostrarPeliculas();
    //System.out.println(mostrarMatriz());
}

public void cargarMatriz(){
    userItem.cargarCalificaciones();
}

public String mostrarMatriz(){
    return userItem.mostrarMatriz();
}

static void appendChars(StringBuilder sb, char c, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sb.append(c);
    }
}


public void mostrarUsuarios(){
    System.out.println("Usuarios:");

    String[] usuarios = userItem.obtenerUsuarios();
    int c = 1;
    for(String us : usuarios){
        System.out.println(c + ". " + us + "\t");
        c++;
    }
}

public void mostrarPeliculas(){
    System.out.println("Peliculas:");

    String[] pelis = userItem.obtenerPeliculas();
    int c = 1;
    for(String pel : pelis){
        System.out.println(c + ". " + pel + "\t");
        c++;
    }
}

**public void mostrarMayor(){
    System.out.println(userItem.darPeliculaMayorPromedio());
}

public void mostrarMenor(){
    System.out.println(userItem.darPeliculaMenorPromedio());
}**
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MenuConsola menu = new MenuConsola();

}

}
```

And this is the matrix one:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Matriz {

private String[] peliculas;
private String[] usuarios;

private int[][] calificaciones;

public Matriz(String[] pelis, String[] users) {
    this.peliculas = pelis;
    this.usuarios = users;
    calificaciones = new int[users.length][pelis.length];
}

public void cargarCalificaciones() {
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/userItem.txt"));

        String linea = "";
        int fila = 0;
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] data = linea.split("\t");
            int col = 0;
            for (String strRatig : data) {
                calificaciones[fila][col] = Integer.parseInt(strRatig);
                col++;
            }

            fila++;
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}

public String mostrarMatriz(){

    String mensaje = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<calificaciones.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < calificaciones[0].length; j++){
            mensaje += " " + calificaciones[i][j];
        }
        mensaje += "\n";
    }

    return (mensaje);
}


public String[] obtenerPeliculas() {
    return peliculas;
}


 */
public String[] obtenerUsuarios() {
    return usuarios;
}


**public String darPeliculaMayorPromedio**(){
    int mayor = calificaciones[0][0];
    String peliMayor = "";
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < calificaciones.length ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < calificaciones[i].length ; j++ )
        {
        if ( calificaciones[i][j] > mayor )
            {
            mayor = calificaciones[i][j];
            peliMayor = peliculas[j];
            }
        }
    }
return peliMayor;
}


**public String darPeliculaMenorPromedio(){**
    int menor = calificaciones[0][0];
    String peliMenor = "";
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < calificaciones.length ; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < calificaciones[i].length ; j++ )
        {
        if ( calificaciones[i][j] < menor )
            {
            menor = calificaciones[i][j];
            peliMenor = peliculas[j];
            }
        }
    }
return peliMenor;
}

}
```

Ok this is all the code, i don't know why isn't it printing something? isn't the array or matrix initializated? I doesn't give me any error when i compile and it executes normally until the last two methods

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I would think its maybe because you haven't initilised your array that your looking through so it would return nothing. Try initialising the array full of values and then you may find you'll get some result

Comment: This is a good suggestion presuming he does not have them declared as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

there doesnt seem to be enough code to accurately answer this question.
Stepping through with a debugger is the best bet, but here are some potential failures I can brainstorm

1. userItem is not static. Since you call userItem.darPeliculaMenorPromedio() in an encapsulated method, you need to either have an instantiated object (which I can see you don't) or the class needs to be static (which I assume it isn't since the methods are not static either) - this should throw an error though, so I assume its not executing.
2. you never execute the functions mostrarMayor and mostrarMenor. I can;t see your main class, and what calls are in it, but you would need to call and execute the two functions in your main.